# how to check if scandir() returns false in php

Tags: php, file, directory, scandir

I will get to the point and explain what I am trying to accomplish then show you what I currently am using to achieve this.

What I want is to check if  directory has any files it at all. Now I usually use readdir and use a while loop to go thru it and what not but I ran up scandir() and thought it would be a bit quicker to use.

I am trying to use a logical operator for when scandir() fails. So for example:

```
if(false!==scandir($main_directory)){
//do something;
}
```

at first it seemed to work however when i implemented something else to be done solely when scandir() fails, it seems like it just ignores it and put it regardless.

any thoughts?

Comment: The code you've put there will "do something" when `scandir` *doesn't* fail. Can you show us the code you used when you "implemented something else to be done solely when scandir() fails"?

Answer (score 0):

Try defining a variable for the scandir function and use it as a condition in your if statement. For example

```
$scan_result=scandir($main_directory);
if(scan_result == false)
{
 //Do something
}
else
{
 //Do something else
}
```